# How can we reusable a Function With Different ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

```
 
    @objc func contextDidSave(_ notification: Notification) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let me = self else { return }
            
            let fileCount = CoreDataService.instance.getUploadedFilesCount(jobId: nil)
            if me.totalFiles == 0 || (fileCount > me.totalFiles) {
                me.totalFiles = fileCount
            }
            // For increase the progress lebel we need the range between 0.1(min) to 1.0(max)
            // So converting all values to float so that we can get decimal value within the range
            let progress = (Float(me.totalFiles) - Float(fileCount)) / Float(me.totalFiles)
            me.progressBarView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
            
            if fileCount == 0 {
                me.progressView.isHidden = true
            } else {
                me.uploadFiles.text = "\("Uploading: ".localized() + (fileCount.description) + " Files left".localized())"
                me.progressView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```

ProgressView is UIView
UploadFile is UILabel
This function is reusable in Two Different ViewController

Comment: you can make an Extension.

Comment: You should decouple this function from your views.  This code belongs in a model object, not in a view controller.  The view controller that calls it can provide a closure or delegate to receive the progress. It can then update its views.